# DataGridComboboxColumn binding with custom Class

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

I have 3 columns in my DataGrid. 2 of them fills good with `string` values. And the last one I need to fill into combobox with properies from my custom class.
Here is code of my class:

```
public class MyClass
{
   string Caption {get;set;}
   int someOtherValue {get;set;}
}
```

I have `List<MyClass> listToBind = GetListOfMyClassInstances();`

I need to fill third DataGridComboboxColumn with `Caption` properies from `listToBind` List. 
And here is my `DataGrid` in XAML:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="294" Margin="18,60,13,0" Name="importedDataTable" VerticalAlignment="Top" CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserReorderColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="FirstValue">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path= myFirstStringValue}"/>
                        <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="SecondValue">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path= mySecondStringValue}"/>
                        <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="ComboBoxData">
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=Caption}"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: are you binding datagrid with List of MyClass?

Comment: first you need to create Properties in MyClass Public. second Caption is just a string, while ItemsSource of combo should be bound to some collection